# Excel 2007 cell comments keep changing shape

Tags: excel, comments, excel-2007

I am working on a document in Excel 2007 which has a notable number of commented cells. But when I save the document for the day to continue the next day several of the comment fields take completely different shapes; the majority shrink down so that only a fraction of the text in them is visible or in some cases that the fields become a lot bigger. Is there any way to fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This little macro should at least fix all the comments in one go:

```
Sub CommentFixer()
    Dim c As Comment
    For Each c In ActiveSheet.Comments
        c.Shape.TextFrame.AutoSize = True
    Next
End Sub
```

**EDIT#1:**

Macros are very easy to install and use:

1. ALT-F11  brings up the VBE window
2. ALT-I
   ALT-M opens a fresh module
3. paste the stuff in and close the VBE window

If you save the workbook, the macro will be saved with it.
If you are using a version of Excel later then 2003, you must save
the file as .xlsm rather than .xlsx

To remove the macro:

1. bring up the VBE window as above
2. clear the code out
3. close the VBE window

To use the macro from Excel:

1. ALT-F8
2. Select the macro
3. Touch RUN

To learn more about macros in general, see:

http://www.mvps.org/dmcritchie/excel/getstarted.htm

and

[http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee814735(v=office.14).aspx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee814735%28v=office.14%29.aspx)

**Macros must be enabled for this to work!**

Comment: Looks good, but does it make them into a single  line? Some of the comments are rather long. And where do I enter it?

Comment: This works like a charm, but when I start to add large comments to cells I might run into trouble... but that's a problem for later on.